# How do I use Java on Spark / RDD to find word frequency in a text file but paragraph by paragraph

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, word-frequency

I am rather new to Spark RDD, I want to use Java on Spark/RDD to find the word frequency in text file, BUT paragraph by paragraph.

If it were in  the whole text file, it seems to straightforward using split, flatMap and reduceByKey. What I need here is word frequency in each of paragraphs (delimited by newline(s)) in the text file.

Please share your thoughts if you were successful in doing so.
Thanks

Comment: Depends if by paragraph you mean newline character, you can use split to split at newline character and then count?

Comment: I try to avoid this question but what have you tried? It is a trivial task which can be handled both manually as well as using Spark transformers.

Comment: It is not trivial as it appears at first, I myself also thought it was trivial. Please let me know if any of you succeeded in it using Apache  Spark and Java RDD (I can use split over split without using Spark/RDD, it was fine). Please. At least, enlighten me how  flatMap can be applied paragraph by paragraph fashion given  an RDD as  [Array[Array[String]]] or give an idea to create an RDD of RDDs (is it possible?)